# What compression class does the BLP image file format uses?

Tags: image, image-compression, compression

Does the BLP file format only use [lossy-compression](/questions/tagged/lossy-compression), [lossless-compression](/questions/tagged/lossless-compression), or both depending on the compressor?

I haven't been able to find a concrete answer to this.

[Lossy and lossless image compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_compression#Lossy_and_lossless_image_compression).

Comment: I’ve never heard of BLP format. Who uses it? Do you have a link?

Comment: @MarkSetchell It's an image texture format created by Blizzard Entertainment and used in their games. [1](https://fileinfo.com/extension/blp), [2](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/BLP_file), [3](https://wowdev.wiki/BLP), [4](https://wow.gamepedia.com/BLP_files).